# Laravel Admin - Voyager route redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, admin, voyager

I have done laravel auth with is_admin field like:

```
if(auth()->user()->is_admin == 1){
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and defined it in route so if the user is admin, can be redirected to voyager dashboard page.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Voyager::routes();
    Route::get('admin', 'HomeController@admin')->middleware('admin');

});
```

When I login, it's redirected to specific page but with error message:

> Target class [VoyagerController] does not exist.

What should I do to return voyager admin page?

Comment: Looks name space issue for `VoyagerController` in your code.

Comment: Can you be more specific? @PrashantDeshmukh.....

Comment: Where are you using `VoyagerController` class?

Comment: Just in routes. Didn't include it anywhere? @PrashantDeshmukh.....

Comment: I guess you have to use `VoyagerController` in routes file, like `use App\Http\VoyagerController;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware ***admin.user***.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Voyager::routes();
    Route::get('admin', 'HomeController@admin')->middleware('admin.user');

});
```

Hope this will work.
This will:

1. Access route only when user is logged in.
2. Redirect to voyager login page when accessing the restricted route.